# DJANGO-PYODBC problems at runserver

Tags: django, django-pyodbc

i'm testing django project to connect a Sql Server database via ODBC.

i have some problems when I try doing runserver of my project

the installed components are:
python 2.7
django 1.10.2
django-pyodbc 0.4.4

the first error was

**File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_pyodbc\introspection.py", line 90,
in get_table_list
    return [TableInfo(row[0].lower(), row[1]) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
NameError: global name 'TableInfo' is not defined**

i tryied to correct ..\django-pyodbc\introspective.py with

try:
    from django.db.backends.base.introspection import (
    BaseDatabaseIntrospection, FieldInfo, TableInfo,
)

instead of

try:
    from django.db.backends.base.introspection import BaseDatabaseIntrospection

but i had the second error

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 604
, in schema_editor
    'The SchemaEditorClass attribute of this database wrapper is still None')
NotImplementedError: The SchemaEditorClass attribute of this database wrapper is
 still None

I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

There are several versions of `django-pyodbc` out there, and it sounds like you're using one that is out of date and doesn't support Django 1.10. The one that seems to be currently best maintained is `django-pyodbc-azure`, which you can install with `pip install django-pyodbc-azure`. I use `django-pyodbc-azure` with Django 1.10 and `pyodbc` 3.0.10 successfully.

More details:

https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure

And just in case you're wondering (I was before using it), it supports both SQL Server AND Azure. You don't have to be using Azure, per se. Good luck!

Comment: Hello FlipperPA, many thanks for your indications. Now it'a all ok.

Comment: Great! Can you mark the answer correct? I'm glad it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `pip install "django-pyodbc-azure<1.11"` so you can use your version of django (<1.11) and follow the instructions in the page:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pyodbc-azure

Comment: Please take a look at ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), specifically the section about adding context to links. Your answer should actually answer the question, rather than simply pointing the user to another site.